# Submitting multiple websites to search engines

Tags: search-engines, link-submission

There are many services that submit your website to multiple search engines. Are there any that allow you to easily submit *multiple* websites to multiple search engines?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of any, however, you will be putting different information each time you submit a site, so it's kind of a non-question. I mean, you have to type out all the information for each site so it makes no difference if you submit one at a time or all at once.

To be honest, you don't need to submit your site to *any* search engines; it's generally regarded as a waste of time. All you need is at least one link (not nofollow) to your site, and the search engines will find and index it just fine. You can also cross-link your sites if they are relevant to each other.

Comment: They will, but it could take a while for them to get to the link that takes them to your site.  If you need traffic fast, there's certainly nothing wrong with raising a flag to grab some attention.

Comment: @Kaji: If you have no links to your site there is no way you'll be "getting traffic fast". Submitting your site may get you indexed a little quicker but it probably won't make much difference.

Comment: I agree with DG. However, I just wanted to ensure my sites get listed in search engines before I get time to build links. (Want to avoid cross-linking my own sites for now).  There are simple ways/workarounds to do it and "paying" to submit to search engines is definitely a no-no.

Answer (score 0):

Intuit's WebListings service will get you submitted to about a hundred different search engines.  It's primarily intended for businesses with a local presence, but it's also a way to get some great coverage with minimal effort.  Granted, it has to be purchased separately for each site you're using it to submit, so it might not be the most effective solution for someone with several sites, but it'll get the job done well for a single site.